# C# Regex: How to break up plain text string

Tags: c#, regex, string, list, file-io

I have a problem which I am wondering how to solve.

I have a String I read in from a pdf file that has a list of questions.
It's in the format of:

> **QUESTION NO: 1**
>
> xxxxxxx (question text)
>
> A) xxxx (multiple choice) B) xxxx C) xxxx ...
>
> Answer:  xxxxx
>
> **QUESTION NO: 2**
>
> xxxxxxx (question text)
>
> .... (etc)

There are about 200 questions in the list.

I am trying to use Regex to break up the text so each question can be in a separate string.

I've done this before with html and xml documents, but they were easy since there are a lot of identifying tags like double quotes, brackets, and parentheses.

But I am clueless as to how to do this with just text.  I've tried a lot of combinations, but it just seems like I can't get the right format:

```
var questionPattern = @"QUESTION NO:(.*)QUESTION NO:";
var questionMatch = Regex.Matches(pdfText, questionPattern, RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

I was wondering, is there a way to do:

```
var questionPattern = @"(?<=QUESTION NO:)[^QUESTION NO:]*";
```

Where the `[^QUESTION NO:]*` reads everything after each Question header until it stops when it comes to the next Question header?

Obviously this is the wrong format, but I hope people will understand what I'm trying to get at.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I know I can probably do this much easily with split, but I would like to know if it can be done with Regex, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the best you're going to get - dependent on Answer. Lookaheads would need to be conditional, and would break the entire expression.

```
(QUESTION NO: \d+[\S\s]*?Answer.*\n*)
```

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/nC6yA1

Comment: remus, I tested in my program, but it doesn't seem to work.  Is there any reason why it might work in your regex tester, and not in c# in particular?

Comment: Oh nevermind, I just needed to get rid of the RegexOptions.Singleline argument.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, since there are 200+ questions in the list, I changed the "\d+" into "\d*"

Comment: awesome! Also, changing + to * won't change the digits that way - * means 0 or more digits, + means 1 or more digits. Since you'll never have no numbers there, it's interchangeable I suppose.